# Calculate Average using PIG | many same entries

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to PIG and therefore an absolute beginner.

I have a .txt file, whose entries look like this:

```html
Name         Matriculation Number Grade Name of Subject
John William 078932832            2.7   Research
John William 078932832            2.3   International Management
John William 078932832            1.7   Math
```

As you can see, inside the text file there are many entries regarding the same person but different subjects with (of course) different grades. 
I would like to compute the average grade of every single student. For the sample data, I have to add 2.7, 2.3 and 1.7 and divide it through the count (three). The result would be 2.23. This procedure should be made for every student inside the list. At the end I want to have a spearate .txt file containing the following:

```html
Name         Matriculation Number Overall Average Grade Number of Subjects
John William 078932832            2.23                  3
```

How can I do this with PIG? Since I am a beginner please provide all steps being necessary to get the result.

Thank you!

Comment: For a member who down voted this question - please comment with whats wrong with question and let the newbies learn about how to ask good questions in SO community.

Answer (score 1):

May need to play with syntax but goes similar to:

```
data_file= load 'yourText.txt' using PigStorage('    ') as (name:chararray,martNum:chararray,grade:float,nameSub:chararray);

groupData= GROUP data_file by (name,martNum);
result= FOREACH groupData GENERATE group, AVG(dat_file.grade),COUNT(data_file.nameSub);
Dump result;
```

this should work, note AVG() is a built in function but it was very buggy in earlier releases so if it complains try using Median() function from DataFu libraries, other work around would be writing python UDF(you can find examples online on official pig website)

Comment: Hi raging_russian, thank you very much for answer! Can you please tell me how I can specify the path to my .txt file with original data? And also how can I get a separate .txt  for the results, which should be save in the file system file?

Comment: If you are running pig locally on your machine, then put your text file in the same directory/folder as your pig script, but if you are running on Hadoop server then you need to upload your text file to HDFS using something like this "hadoop fs -put textfile.txt desiredName.txt"